Convert string_view to char* and walk away with it
In this post, How you convert a std::string_view to a const char*?, the question was raised how to convert std::string_view into char* and the answer is basically:

make a temporary string from the view (makes a copy) and use its c_str()

That works if you're not planning on keeping the char* beyond the lifetime of the string. However, I do want to keep it. Hence, in contrast to the linked Q&A, I have to copy the underlying string (thus copying the memory a second time).
Moreover, I am settled for unique_ptr<char[]> instead of std::string due to its size.
What is the best way to do this conversion from string_view to unique_ptr<char[]>?
First Try: The intuitive first approach is to just make a copy of the temporary c_str(), but now I've copied my character array twice: once to create the temporary string, and another time to make a permanent char* that survives the destruction of my temporary string.
auto sv_to_cp(const string_view s) {
  unique_ptr<char[]> result = make_unique<char[]>(s.size() + 1);
  string tmp{s}; // first copy
  strcpy(result.get(), tmp.c_str()); // second copy
  return result;
}

Second Try: Maybe I can somehow std::move out the temporary string into my char*? To this end, I'd have to assign the string's buffer to it, and somehow tell the string that it no longer owns its buffer, but I have no idea how that might work.
Third Try: I could skip the temporary string altogether and just create my char* manually with one more character than the string_view for the zero-termination. However, this seems clunky and error prone, and surely not the intended way of doing that, is it?
auto sv_to_cp(const string_view s) {
  unique_ptr<char[]> result = make_unique<char[]>(s.size() + 1);
  ranges::copy_n(s, s.size(), result.get());
  result[s.size()] = 0;
  return result;
}

So, my question is: is this really the intended way of converting a string_view to char* (or derivatives)?
EDIT: for anyone wondering why I prefer a char* (or the conceptually equal unique_ptr<char[]>) over a std::string: I have a large number of std::variants that almost always hold an integer (uintptr_t) and, occasionally hold a text. Thus, it would be a colossal waste of space were it to be able to hold a std::string.

is this really the intended way of converting a string_view to char*?  No.

Who do you expect to be the owner of the zero terminated char array related to char* you want to "walk away with" ? (a string_view is not an owner anyway).

What's wrong with keeping that std::string as a long-term storage for the characters? Why do you want to copy them elsewhere?

@wohlstad the unique_ptr<char[]> should own the memory. I just wrote char* as a representative of unique_ptr<char[]>
I'm aware that I'll have to make at least 1 copy because the string_view doesn't own the memory, but I want to avoid makeing 2 copies.

@HolyBlackCat std::string is too large for my std::variant, it basically makes my variant 32bytes while I'll only use 8bytes of it most of the time, so that's super wasteful

Then your last snippet already looks optimal to me.

a char* is just a pointer. If you want to keep the string longer than the original around you need to make a copy, no way to avoid that

std::string is too large for my std::variant...  That was omitted from your original question.  Sounds like that is an important detail:  classic XY problem.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I'm aware that I'll have to make at least 1 copy because the string_view doesn't own the memory, but I want to avoid makeing 2 copies.

I have problems to understand your question and comments, because you mix up the char* with the actual character array. For example in "First Try" you say you copy c_str but its not clear if you refer to copying the pointer or copying the array. c_str is a pointer. In any case I do not see the 2nd copy. You should show the code that has this 2nd copy. Questions that ask to avoid code without showing that code are extremely difficult to understand.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai You're right that I'm not being 100% exact here. I use "copy of "  as an abbreviation for "copy of the memory pointed to by ". Since I never worry about copying pointers, can we agree that, whenever it's not clear if I'm talking about copying pointers or copying memory, I'm actually talking about copying memory?

In all your considerations, you never considered that the std::string_view might not be a view over an 0x00 terminated char[]. What if it isn’t? What if it is … and so on. Getting the char* it is viewing is the easy part. Using that char* as an 0x00 terminated char[] is the more difficult part because you have to make the assumption. You can check before using it though.

@ChukwujiobiCanon thanks for the hint, you're right, I might waste a byte of memory by appending a zero char; It was just a toy implementation to give the rough idea of what I mean by "do it manually"; I'm still hoping there is a more elegant way of doing what I want ^^

sure we can agree on that. I still have no clue what "First Try" implementation would look like. And why it would copy the string twice

the question you link is about not making a copy. You need to make a copy. I dont see whats wrong with simply doing std::string copy{s};. This is the easiest way to copy the string and you get the char* that you want

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I added some code now :)

why do you need the char* managed by a std::unique_ptr ? Why not by std::string?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai in the question I link, the memory pointed to by the produced char* will be freed so I cannot read the char* afterwards. Thus, if I want to keep ("walk away with") the (char array pointed to by the) char*, then I have to make a second copy.

The reason to not create  a string (in the q&a you link, and elsewhere) is because one doesnt want/need a copy. You do need a copy. Hence, it isnt obvious why do think you need to copy twice

You can keep the std::string. You dont have to make another copy once you have that. It manages the memory, it grants you access to char*. The another copy can be removed, just do return tmp;

you ask for char*. A unique_ptr is not a char* it encapsualtes one. Maybe you have reason to prefer it over a std::string (which encapsulates a char* as well), but that reasons are not obvious. If there are none, use the std::string, if there are some use your 3rd option. The elegant way you look for is std::string copy{the_view}; only if you need something more complicated you use something more complicated.

fwiw, you do not have to add "EDIT" or similar to the question. The edit history is available here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78882232/revisions

I found the reasons in the comments. If this is an important requirement (too large) you have to mention it in the quesiton.

and then, frankly, the quesiton is borderline offtopic. You have code that works but want something more "elegant". What is elegant? And not quite clear:  Why do you consider it error prone? The function does the right thing, it return the thing you want. Why is it error prone?

You are basically asking for a code review. Perhaps you can try here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Just make sure to read their rules about how to write quesiton, and make sure to present them the code and the requirements.

unique_ptr<char[]> result = make_unique<char[]>(s.size() + 1); that's just an overly complicated alternative to std::string. Also do you really understand the concepts of "ownership" and "view" ? If you need a char pointer for the duration of a call to a legacy API,  just use the string_views data()` method.

@PepijnKramer no, it is not. sizeof(string) == 32 and sizeof(unique_ptr<char[]>) == 8. This difference is important to me. And I dare say that I do understand the difference, yes. I need the c-string longer than for the duration of a call, yes.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai thanks for the pointer to the codereview page, I'll check that out :)

editorial note. THe most important information in your question is still only a footnote. You do not have to keep previous iterations of the quesiton intact. Write it it so that its current version is concise (and again, previous versions are accessible here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78882232/revisions, not sure if its behind a rep wall though)

please review my edit. I am not quite sure about it, because you ask for char*, but from comments I understood you actually want a unique_ptr. If thats the case you should also change the title.

I don't think the title should insist on unique_ptr<char[]> instead of char* since the latter is much more common and it's not relevant for the question whether or not the memory is freed by hand or automatically by a destructor. I can live with your edits, but I don't think the title should change.

@igel "sizeof(string) == 32" - that is implementation-defined. The only reason std::string would ever be that large is if it implements a SSO (short string optimization) buffer. If you don't want that, you can always implement your own string class that does not have that buffer. That way, you can easily cut the size almost in half to suit your needs. A string class only needs 3 data members at a minimum - a pointer to the character data, the number of characters used in that data, and the allocated capacity of that data.

@RemyLebeau writing my own string class is actually very close to what I want. In fact my question can be stated as: how to write a constructor for my own string class that takes a string_view and makes at most 1 copy of the memory?
Maybe that would have been an easier way to formulate it. An even better question may be how to construct such a string from a std::string&& without copies :)

Stupid question why can't you get something else in your function than the string_view? Is it a cut from a json or something like that?

@igel writing a string class from scratch is fairly trivial. Plenty of questions on StackOverflow about that. And you already know how to copy data from a std::string_view. But, you can't steal the data from a std::string, you can only move it to another std::string. Otherwise you must make a copy for your own purpose.

@Surt string_view is the most general choice. If the user of my code has a string, then they can make a string_view from it trivially. If the user has a string_view, they can just call the function. If instead, my function took a string, then the user would have to make a copy before calling the function, and then, I would have to make another copy to get the data out of the string (since I cannot steal from string apparently)
